# Best way to trim text to fit a line limit? (Javascript or C#)

Tags: javascript, c#, html, character

I have a component that displays text on a few lines, with a height limit, so that the text gets cut off past a certain height. However, there is a 'more' link at the end of the text, and this link needs to be visible, so I'm trimming the text in the backend based on how many lines of text are available. I figured out an approximate character count that fits the number of lines available, and trimmed the text to that count minus the length of the link (">> more")

[image]

```
var maxCharacters = 224;
var numberOfLines = 0;
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(newsItem.Topline))
{
    numberOfLines ++;
    if (newsItem.Topline.Length > 65)
    {
        numberOfLines ++;
    }
    if (newsItem.Topline.Length > 130)
    {
        numberOfLines ++;
    }
}
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(newsItem.Headline))
{
    numberOfLines++;
    if (newsItem.Headline.Length > 55)
    {
        numberOfLines++;
    }
    if (newsItem.Headline.Length > 110)
    {
        numberOfLines++;
    }
}

// max lines available is 4 lines, or 65*4 characters
maxCharacters = maxCharacters - (56*numberOfLines);

var description = maxCharacters <= 0 ? String.Empty : ApplyMaximumLetterCount(newsItem, maxCharacters);
litDescription.Text = description;

hplUrlRight.Text = @"» more";
hplUrlRight.NavigateUrl = newsItem._Url;
```

---

```
public string ApplyMaximumLetterCount(INews newsItem, int maxLength)
{
    var description = newsItem.Description;
    var letterCount = description.Length;
    if (letterCount > maxLength)
    {
        var diff = letterCount - maxLength;

        if (diff >= description.Length)
        {
            return "";
        }

        description = description.Substring(0, (description.Length - (diff + 3)));
        description = TrimToLastWord(description);
        description += "...";
    }
    return description;
}

public string TrimToLastWord(string description)
{
    var continuationCharacters = new List<char>() { ',', ';', '-'};
    var lastCharacter = description[description.Length - 1];
    if (lastCharacter == ' ')
    {
        // if last character before last is a semicolon or comma, trim one more and return
        // else, trim space and return
        if (continuationCharacters.Contains(description[description.Length - 2]))
        {
            return description.Substring(0, description.Length - 2);
        }
        return description.Substring(0, description.Length - 1);
    }
    return TrimToLastWord(description.Substring(0, description.Length - 1));
}
```

My client isn't satisfied with this. He wants the text to extend as close to the right margin as possible. I suggested alternatives such as cutting off the text in the middle of a word (i.e. not trimming to the last complete word, but just cutting off the text to the maximum character count); giving the "more" link absolute position and white background so that it just hides whatever is directly behind it (this has the possibility of cutting off words in the middle of a letter); or extending the text all the way to the margin and displaying the "more" link beneath, but my client doesn't like any of these options.

So, does anyone know of any better methods to implement a line limit while displaying the "more" link at the end of the text? Is there any way I haven't thought of that I can get the text as close to the right margin as possible while still fitting in the "more" link?

I'm reluctant to do a Javascript solution because that would cause a flicker on the screen where the full text would show momentarily before the Javascript function completed; I'd prefer to keep it in the backend, but if a good Javascript solution exists I'll suggest it.

Comment: Check out css3 properties.http://dev.mobify.com/blog/multiline-ellipsis-in-pure-css/

Comment: Why not forget all that back-end code, realize that front-ends will have different screen sizes and resolutions, so instead use a responsive web design technique like CSS [`text-overflow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow) and some simple JavaScript to show the overflow upon a click.

Comment: Could you put the link in a separate div and use z-index to locate it on the box which contains the text? And as @Scott said, you must consider that the page has a proper view on every devices ;)